# php imap_open with microsoft exchange (outlook web app)

Tags: php, exchange-server, outlook-web-app, imap-open

The company where I work moved from Lotus Notes to Microsoft Exchange with Outlook Web App. With Lotus Notes, my PHP script works just fine, since 2014. Since the move to MS Exchange, PHP's `imap_open` cannot access this mail account anymore.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$emHOST = '{mail.company.com/tls/novalidate-cert}';
$emUSER = 'e-mail@company.com';
$emPASW = 'password';
$emPOP = imap_open($emHOST, $emUSER, $emPASW);
print_r(imap_errors());
```

Whatever I try via PHP, I get 'LOGIN failed':

```
Array
(
    [0] => LOGIN failed.
    [1] => LOGIN failed.
    [2] => LOGIN failed.
    [3] => Too many login failures
)
```

I tried with `/ssl` instead of `/tls` but that gives a timeout on port 993.

I can, however, login with the same username and password via https://mail.company.com/owa in a web browser.

Does anyone have some tips for me to get this thing running again?
Thanks!

Comment: Last time I worked with Exchange, it did not enable IMAP by default. There's probably a setting you have to toggle on the server.

Comment: I got a new answer: I need Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication. Well, new challenges lay ahead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of waiting it turns out that responsible IT-department has now finally configured OWA correctly. I can use `'{mail.company.com:143}'` to log in the IMAP mailbox.

Comment: Hi MrMacvos,

I have tried solution as are you saying. but i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Can you please share full script of config. ? Thank you.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Current solution:
`$emHOST = '{host.name[:port]}';
$emUSER = 'your.email@address.com';
$emPASW = 'your password';

// Connect to the mail server and grab headers from the mailbox
$emPOP = imap_open($emHOST, $emUSER, $emPASW);
if($emPOP === false) {
 print("Error getting email. ($emHOST)\n");
 exit;
}

// Get number of emails
$headers = imap_headers($emPOP);

// Loop through each email
for($n=1; $n<=count($headers); $n++) {

 $st = imap_fetchstructure($emPOP, $n);
 $hi = imap_headerinfo($emPOP, $n);
....
....
}`

Answer (score 0):

With MS Exchange IMAP or POP3 is normally not enabled as mentioned by Microsoft [here for IMAP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124022(v=exchg.150).aspx):

> By default, the two IMAP4 services, the Microsoft Exchange IMAP4
>   service and the Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 Backend service, aren’t
>   started on computers running Microsoft Exchange Server 2013. You must
>   start these two services to allow your email clients to connect to
>   Exchange using IMAP4. When these services are running, Exchange 2013
>   accepts unsecured IMAP4 client communications on port 143 and over
>   port 993 using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

or [here for POP3](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997475(v=exchg.150).aspx):

> By default, the two POP3 services, the Microsoft Exchange POP3 service
>   and the Microsoft Exchange POP3 Backend service, aren’t started on
>   computers running Microsoft Exchange Server 2013. You must start these
>   two services to allow your email clients to connect to Exchange using
>   POP3. When these services are running, Exchange 2013 accepts unsecured
>   POP3 client communications on port 110 and over port 995 using Secure
>   Sockets Layer (SSL).

This is due to the reason that an MS Outlook client used [*MAPI*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124497(v=exchg.150).aspx) or [*MAPI over HTTP*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635177(v=exchg.160).aspx) to communicate with the MS Exchange Server (similar like an Lotus Notes client didn´t need POP3 or IMAP, it used a [TPC/IP connection over port 1352](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248258)) [SideNote: [MS Outlook for MAC used EWS]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984202(v=office.16).aspx).

So please check with your exchange Administrator if IMAP is enabled, he might enable that for you.

If not you way you might wish to use [Exchange Webservices (EWS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) in a further version with your Script. A good starting point might be ["How to: Work with Exchange mailbox items by using EWS in Exchange"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: Hi BastianW, thanks for your answer. I'll forward your tips to our IT-department so they can have a look at it.

Comment: you are welcome. Please also accept this posting as answer so that it isn´t any longer flagged on StackOverflow as open :).

Comment: IT reported back that IMAP services are running. They tested this by creating an IMAP account for this email-address in Thunderbird. Hmm. I'm not sure if that is a good test. I am now hoping for an answer from the IT-Email team.

Comment: Some companies (like the one where I work for) have two email environment one for exchange which are used by the VIPs and another cost free one for the normal users (which used IMAP and Thunderbird). So maybe they did a test but on the wrong environment ;-).